# Is there a way to automate deletion of cloudwatch alarms that have resources which have been deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation

Currently I am working for a client. I am auditing all cloudwatch alarms, there are a lot of ec2 instances which do not exist anymore but still have alarms created for them. Is there a way to automate deletion of such alarms where the AWS resource on which they are enabled has been deleted. It would be great since I have to do this task manually and doing  it for 500+ ec2 instances manually is insane.

Comment: Yes. You have to develop a custom solution for that.

Comment: Could elaborate with an example of how can I do that ?